# Web mode -indentation is misaligned on skipping semicolons

Tags: indentation, javascript, web-mode

When i indent javascript code (inside html - web mode) that has no semicolons in it, the next statements are indented right with two extra spaces,

```
    <script>
 function processTemplates(){
   var tmpldata = $( "#suiteSummaryTemplate" ).tmpl( tempData );
   $(tmpldata).appendTo( "#example" )
     //$( "#example" ).html(tmpldata)
     var logSummTmplStr = $( "#logSummaryTemplate" ).tmpl( logSummaryData )
     $(logSummTmplStr).appendTo( "#logs_table" )
     //$("#logs_table").html(logSummTmplStr)
} 
</script>
```

After adding semicolons to a line, it works properly like,

```
  var tmpldata = $( "#suiteSummaryTemplate" ).tmpl( tempData );
  $(tmpldata).appendTo( "#example" )
```

In `javascript-mode`, when i place the same code in a js file (after removing the script tag), it works properly.

How can i achieve this correct indentation without forcing the user to use semicolons everywhere?

Comment: `M-x` `report-emacs-bug`?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem and couldn't. Try opening emacs with `emacs -q` and see if it is still reproducible. 

It seems like you use  a combination of `newline` and `indent-relative` but I don't know for sure.

Comment: hi caisah, this error is seen in javascript code embedded inside html in web mode. in javascript mode, it works good... sorry for the wrong inputs, man...

Comment: I don't really know what to make of this: https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/503 might be a `wont-fix`

Comment: @MadhavanKumar Seems like a known issue, may want to bring more attention to it on github.

Comment: Is there a resolution to this?   (I have the same problem, obviously :) )